# Rails forms: after click - disable link

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have more forms in may rails apps with standart 'Save' and 'Update' buttons. How to make this button non-active (disabled) after first click to this link?

Answer (score 19):

You can use the `disable_with` option with the form_tag and form_for helpers
In the case of form_tag, you can use

```
submit_tag "Complete sale", :disable_with => "Please wait..."
```

In the case of form_for, you can use

```
   f.submit 'Create', :disable_with => "Creating..."
```

source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag

Comment: This is deprecated in rails 3 and 4

Comment: `data: { disable_with: "Creating..." }` is the way to do it in rails 4.

Answer (score 2):

With jquery you can make it really easy

```
$('form').submit(function(){
$('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

The above looks for ALL forms and makes the submit button disabled after clicking submit. This is the preferred method because the enter button would also triggers a submit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with javascript, then why not use event delegation?

```
$(document.body).delegate("form.active","click",function(){
    this.className = "clicked";
});
```

This delegates a click event to every form in the page with a class of active (equally you could limit this to every form in a container by using a different context ie $("#container").delegate(...) or omit the active class) and changes the class from being active to clicked

```
$(document.body).delegate("form.clicked","submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This delegates a submit event to every form on the page with a className of clicked and stops the form from being submitted.

Alternatively, you could use the first delegate function to bind a submit event directly to the form itself (so replace both of the above functions with the following).

```
$(document.body).delegate("form","click",function(){
    $(this).submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is soo late but some one my found it useful.

Some times `:disable_with`does not work in rails. 
For this u've to check if `jquery-rails` gem is added in your gemfile or not.

Then use `'data-disable-with' => "SUBMITTING"` option.